# Receive bytes from websocket - windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, stream, websocket, windows-store-apps

I try receive bytes from websocket in my windows 8 app but if I use  `readStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);` to get bytes but app work unusually. Does anyone know how I can get byte array from receive bytes? I send 7 bytes to server and then I get 1752 bytes but now I don't know how get these bytes, I m possible only count bytes. I use standard windows 8 sample 
Connecting with WebSockets sample (Windows 8).

```
private async void ReceiveData(object state)
{
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    try
    {
        Stream readStream = (Stream)state;                
        int read = await readStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
        bytesReceived += read;
        MarshalText(DataReceivedField, bytesReceived.ToString(), false);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            readStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }                   
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to communicate with a WebSockets server as if it were a normal TCP connection. That is not going to work, because WebSocket is actually an own protocol above TCP which surrounds the payload data with framing information and also encodes the payload data. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 for more information about the WebSocket protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Recieving data is not as simple as it should be.
I prefere using an already coded class wich you can find in different forms.

A very nice project is this one: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/422291/user-friendly-asynchronous-event-driven-tcp-client

Comment: OK so I get it to work. Variable readBuffer contain all bytes now I only parse bytes which I need to work.